# Using BrowserRouter, how can I refresh page without getting a 404 on production server?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I understand how BrowserRouter and HashRouter work in React Router v4. I am currently using BrowserRouter so I don't get such ugly URLs. I have seen many examples, most of which are outdated. I would like to know how I can refresh the page on a route without getting a 404 on the production server? Essentially having React re-render the component. I should also mention that I am using create react app and the react-scripts provided to start and build the project. I tried the historyApiFallback thing in webpack and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Do you have fallback logic in your **server** to redirect requests to `index.html` if your API or similar routes are not hit?

Comment: No, would you be able to show me what that looks like or how I would do that? My API is a node.js/GraphQL server on AWS.

Comment: You need clarity in your question what server technology you are using and how you are specifically loading the React application.

Comment: The client app is hosted on a windows server. Is there something I need to set in IIS?

Comment: Yes. You would probably need to add a [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module). There are tutorials such as the [following](https://medium.com/@mateioprea/setting-up-a-react-app-with-react-router-in-iis-71cb86aee376) covering this. You are effectively telling to route unmatched paths to the React applications index.html so that it can always handle the routing internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple application and wan't to avoid server side rendering of routes, you can use "React Snap"

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snap

Once you configure it, it pre-renders your web app routes into static HTML. I use it for a lot of my react+router apps and I love it.